# Python Turtle nested squares - how to fix the second square extra shift?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have started learning Python and playing around with the Turtle drawing various shapes. I decided to draw n nested squares and have achieved the following result:

[image]

However as you can see, after the 1st iteration the position of the second square has been shifted too much to the left/down direction. And all the following squares look ok. I expect all the squares to have the same offset from each other.

How should I modify my code to fix this?

```
def draw_squares(side_len, num_squares, side_increment):
    for i in range(num_squares):
        draw_polygon(4, side_len)
        pen.up()
        pen.setposition(x - side_len/2, y - side_len/2)
        pen.down()
        side_len += side_increment


side_length = 50
num_of_squares = 10
side_incr = 40

draw_squares(side_length, num_of_squares, side_incr)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that the first square is starting at (0,0).
You can easily correct this problem by setting the position before calling the `draw_polygon()` function.

```py
def draw_squares(side_len, num_squares, side_increment):
    for i in range(num_squares):
        pen.up()
        pen.setposition(x - side_len/2, y - side_len/2)
        pen.down()
        draw_polygon(4, side_len)
        side_len += side_increment
```

If this doesn't solve the problem pls share your `draw_polygon()` function.

Comment: You are right, setting the position before calling `draw_polygon()` solved the problem. Thank you!)